# Rails debounce delayed job background task? removing duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, delayed-job

**Debouncing** is a common method to postpone a function/job from executing until after certain time has passed.

**Use-case:** A conversation with active chatting from multiple users, they should not receive an email notification for each message typed. But more than likely after a few minutes of silence, if the messages are unread, the user should see a notification.

**Delayed_Job**

Has no solution, has related issues: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/72

**Sidekiq**

https://github.com/hummingbird-me/sidekiq-debounce

Comment: In RabbitMQ, I use a dead letter exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing yourself is not so bad.

```rb
class AdminJob
  def self.debounce(job, args={})
    handler = YAML.dump(job)
    count = Delayed::Job.where(handler: handler).where('locked_at IS NULL').delete_all
    Rails.logger.info("deleted: #{count} jobs")
    Delayed::Job.enqueue(job, args)
  end
end
```

Instead of writing:

```rb
Delayed::Job.enqueue(YourJobName.new(account_id), {run_at: 10.minutes.from_now})
```

You now write:

```rb
AdminJob.debounce(YourJobName.new(account_id), {run_at: 10.minutes.from_now})
```

Delayed job serializes your job params in `YAML` and then saves it to the database as `handler`. So if you call `AdminJob.debounce(...)` 10 times in a row, it will delete before each.

Make sure to give yourself time (5.minutes, etc) to give users to keep taking actions. If you run your job after 1 second, its likely they'll keep taking actions and trigger again.

*Yes i'm answering my own question 3 years later...*

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess is that doing a delete_all query will cause the db engine to still need to do a db lookup (similar to a select...where). And doing this on a serialized column (a long string) on a large database of thousands (or tens of thousands) of records could be really slow.  If this was done with a unique key or signature of the job that can be well indexed, then this would be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is schedule a periodic task, lets say every 5 minutes that checks if there is someone who has to be notified. Yes it seems an expensive operation, but for your use case I don't see (for now) others solutions. So lets say you have 10 users that uses a chat. Every 5 minutes you could check if there are users that didn't see some messages, and if so you notify them only if they are inactive from N minutes.

To schedule such task you could use [crono](https://github.com/plashchynski/crono) gem. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396789/7237629).

Crono lets you do thing like that:

```
Crono.perform(CheckUsersToBeNotifiedJob).every 5.minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Delayed Job as the implementation for Active Job then take a look at the 'activejob-trackable' gem.
https://github.com/ignatiusreza/activejob-trackable

It uses another table that tracks the jobs and can throttle and debounce.